# CSS: Full width row of proportionally scaled elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Given a set of elements -- let's say images -- of varying resolutions: What is the cleanest way of proportionally resizing these elements to the same height, so that the elements take 100% of the containing element?

To clarify the question, the following example visualises what I am trying to do in two steps (by resizing the elements to the same height first and by subsequently changing the width to match the container), see https://jsfiddle.net/vawn69rn/

```
<span>
  <h1>Initial images:</h1>
  <div style="background-color:red; height: 200px; width:100px; float: left;"></div>
  <div style="background-color:green; height: 100px; width:100px; float: left;"></div>
  <div style="background-color:blue; height: 50px; width:50px; float: left;"></div>
  <div style="background-color:black; height: 100px; width:200px; float: left;"></div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</span>

<span>
  <h1>Container:</h1>
  <div style="background-color:none; border: #000 solid 1px; height: 200px; width:300px; "></div>
</span>

<span>
  <h1>Step 1, equalise height:</h1>
  <div style="background-color:red; height: 200px; width:100px; float: left;"></div>
  <div style="background-color:green; height: 200px; width:200px; float: left;"></div>
  <div style="background-color:blue; height: 200px; width:200px; float: left;"></div>
  <div style="background-color:black; height: 200px; width:400px; float: left;"></div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</span>

<span>
  <h1>Step 2, Use full width of container:</h1>
  <div style="background-color:none; border: #000 solid 1px; height: 200px; width:300px; ">
    <div style="background-color:red; height: 66.66px; width:33.33px; float: left;"></div>
    <div style="background-color:green; height: 66.66px; width:66.66px; float: left;"></div>
    <div style="background-color:blue; height: 66.66px; width:66.66px; float: left;"></div>
    <div style="background-color:black; height: 66.66px; width:133.33px; float: left;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</span>
```

In contrast to the example, however, I am interested in a portable solution without hard-coding any values.

I suppose this can be realised using flexboxes, but I haven't found a clean solution yet.

Comment: You can't equalize height like that, when row wraps, without a script

Answer (score 0):

Using flexbox: I made the main container flex and the container holding the supposed image. See code below. But i dint try it with real images. You should try that and see how it looks. Hope this helps

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    border: #000 solid 1px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}
.step1 {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.step1 div {
  height: 100% !Important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="step1">
    <div style="background-color:red; height: 200px; width:100px; float: left;"></div>
    <div style="background-color:green; height: 200px; width:200px; float: left;"></div>
    <div style="background-color:blue; height: 200px; width:200px; float: left;"></div>
    <div style="background-color:black; height: 200px; width:400px; float: left;"></div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but there are two issues here:
1. You start of with elements of the same height.
2. The aspect ratio in your solution is NOT kept. The square boxes for instance (green and blue), are no squares any longer.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1, equalize height: set some height to the container div & set image height to 100%. This will maintain the aspect ratio when resizing. You should not resize both height & width, only in case of images.

```
.div1 {
    height: 200px;
}
.div1 img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Step 2, Use full width of container: same as previous but set the width to 100% instead of width.

```
.div1 {
    width: 200px;
}
.div1 img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Notify me if you edit and show it does work, and I retract my down vote...hey, I might even upvote instead